# Mock a specific base class method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a scenario where I am confused how to mock the base class.

Code of my base class:

```
public class ParentClass
{
   public virtual int Sum()
   {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Code of my inherited class:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public override int Sum()
    {
        return 1 + base.Sum();
    }
}
```

Now I want to test inherited ChildClass.Sum() method but want to mock the ParentClass.Sum() method so that it returns some fixed value other than zero.

> Unable to figure out what can be done to tell the mock object to mock the base class method but use actual implementation for the derived class method.

This is test code I have written.

```
[TestClass]
public class ChildClassTest
{
    private Mock<ParentClass> _parentClassMock;


    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
      _parentClassMock = new Mock<ParentClass>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenChildClass_WhenAdding_ThenResultShouldSumUp()
    {
        //Arrange
        SetupParentClassSumMethod();
        ChildClass child = new ChildClass();

        //Act
        int result = child.Sum();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(21, result);   
     }

     private void SetupParentClassSumMethod()
     {
        _parentClassMock.Setup(x => x.Sum()).Returns(20);
     }
}
```

The Parent class is still returning value as 0.

Is what I want to do achievable or not?

Comment: If you want to unit test code of ChildClass then you don't need to create mock of any class. What exactly you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Added test class code, please let me know if still my questions/expectation is unclear.

Comment: Mocking is a process where you inject functionality that you don't want to test or an external service, i.e. a service call. Mocking in this scenario makes no sense. You can't mock the base class of the instanciated class, the instanciated class includes the base class and all it's functionality. If the base class called an external service then you would use dependency injection and mock that dependency, what you have here doesn't fit mocking.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to know whether it’s achievable or not.

Comment: If you use decorator design pattern then you can achieve it https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp

Comment: Thank you, Aman, but in our organization, we don't touch our implementation code to develop tests.

Comment: Other problem is that the child object and the mock of parent are different objects, they are not connected to each other in any way. So the child returns 1 and the parent mocked object returns 20.

Comment: @dee That is what my question is all about, how to connect those two object?

Comment: You can't do what you want when you're using inheritance. You can only mock a new Sum on top of the existing two, you cannot substitute out the base method only. If you need to do this you need to separate the two such that the second class uses the first one as a dependency that can be switched out with a mock. Inheritance is a different beast.

Comment: @KunalKhivensara because you are using inheritance you are not able to achieve what it is you want without refactoring the base class. Once suggestion would be to introduce a core method that does the core functionality that can be overridden.

Comment: Basically here you want to mock system under test which is conceptually wrong. One suggestion is to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance principle.

Comment: _but in our organization, we don't touch our implementation code to develop tests_ - if you write tests - you should write "testable" software, or you end up with very complicated and fragile tests which tightly depend on implementation details. In your particular case - you should testing your child class without knowing about base class

Answer (score 2):

*Is what I want to do achievable or not?*

No, I think this is not achievable with mock of parent class. What you can do would be to create a testable class of the child class and set the value of `Sum` which you want to return from the base class.

```
public class ChildClassTestable : ChildClass
{
    public int SumOfParentReturnValue { set; get; }

    public override int Sum()
    {
        return 1 + SumOfParentReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Then the test could look like this. But is this what you need?

```
//Arrange
ChildClassTestable child = new ChildClassTestable {SumOfParentReturnValue = 20};

//Act
int result = child.Sum();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(21, result);
```